# key cannot be modified or marked as modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

My database SQL tables relation as following, it is looks simply, but relation is a little complicated as following,
`ProblemLog` class has 6 properties each one is 1 to 1 relation to other class ‘table’ `ActionUser`, each `ActionUser` consist of `LogUser` class and date property only.

Once I modified the `LogUser` from dropdown list inside the `ProblemLog` . `ActionUser` and try to save the dbcontext, I got this exception
System.InvalidOperationException:

`The property 'LogUser.Id' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified.`

To change the principal of an existing entity with an identifying foreign key, first delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges', and then associate the dependent with the new principal.
Are there any workaround ??

Comment: You have a primary key in the database that cannot be modified using an INSERT instruction which would add the same key twice.  The solution is to use an UPDATE instead which modifies the existing value.

Comment: The object is the same and was tracking by EF core, inside the Object I have other entity linked to the parent as 1 to 1 relation, I made this sub-Entity to be selectable from dropdown list, once the selection change the foreign Key ID in the parent object update with the new ID that selected, when I save the DBContext I receive this exception, Can you help for this?